# Separate a Single Column by a Delimiter- Different Number of Delimiters

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data frame that includes a column with a categorization. Levels of categorization are separated with a /. Some observations are categorized to a finer detail than others. Some have no category provided, others have one, two  three, or four. Some dummy data is below:

```
test.data<-data.frame(obs=c("obs1","obs2","obs3","obs4","obs5","obs6","obs7",
                            "obs8","obs9","obs10"),
                      cat=c("car/ford/escort","truck/chevy","car",NA,
                            "car/volkswagon/jetta/turbo",
                            "truck/dodge/ram/superduty","truck","car/ford/escort",
                            NA,"truck/ford"))

test.data
     obs                        cat
1   obs1            car/ford/escort
2   obs2                truck/chevy
3   obs3                        car
4   obs4                       <NA>
5   obs5 car/volkswagon/jetta/turbo
6   obs6  truck/dodge/ram/superduty
7   obs7                      truck
8   obs8            car/ford/escort
9   obs9                       <NA>
10 obs10                 truck/ford
```

I would like to stick four columns to the end of this data frame-one for each level of categorization. When a particular observation lacks all levels of detail, it would return `NA`.

```
desired.data
     obs                        cat  cat1       cat2   cat3      cat4
1   obs1            car/ford/escort   car       ford escort      <NA>
2   obs2                truck/chevy truck      chevy   <NA>      <NA>
3   obs3                        car   car       <NA>   <NA>      <NA>
4   obs4                       <NA>  <NA>       <NA>   <NA>      <NA>
5   obs5 car/volkswagon/jetta/turbo   car volkswagon  jetta     turbo
6   obs6  truck/dodge/ram/superduty truck      dodge    ram superduty
7   obs7                      truck truck       <NA>   <NA>      <NA>
8   obs8            car/ford/escort   car       ford escort      <NA>
9   obs9                       <NA>  <NA>       <NA>   <NA>      <NA>
10 obs10                 truck/ford truck       ford   <NA>      <NA>
```

I have attempted to use `separate` to no avail.

```
    require(tidyr)
    separate(test.data,cat,c("cat1","cat2","cat3","cat4"))
    Error: Values not split into 4 pieces at 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Does anyone know how best to solve a problem like this?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and providing me with another related question on SO.  As an FYI, the `cSplit` method spun for 15 minutes and then R failed when I tried to stop it. The `tidyr` method took less than one minute.  I did not try the `read.table` method. I am looking at about 11.5M rows. If I should include this information in another location, please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: @NickC You might use `tstrsplit` from the devel version of `library(data.table)`. i.e.  `setDT(test.data)[, paste0('cat', 1:4):=tstrsplit(cat, '/')]` should be fast

Comment: If you're using tidyr you can modify the parameters in separate as follows to produce the desired results: `separate(test.data, cat, paste0('cat', 1:4), '/', remove=FALSE, extra='merge')`

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback.